# Invalid Timestamp when inserting to teradata with BTEQ

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-insert, create-table

So I want to insert something into a table which was created before with bteq.
I already googled for this (e.g. [here](http://downloads.teradata.com/forum/database/6760-invalid-timestamp)) however I already cast on the column  and that did not erase the error.

The creation statement looks like this:

```
.logmech LDAP
.logon databae/user_id,pwd
.set width 256
.set retcancel on database libname;
DATABASE libname;
create MULTISET table libname.IRIS( "SEPAL_LENGTH" FLOAT,  "SEPAL_WIDTH" FLOAT,  "PETAL_LENGTH" FLOAT,  "PETAL_WIDTH" FLOAT,  "TARGET" FLOAT,  "TIMESTAMP1" TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS.S(6)' DEFAULT NULL ,  "NULL_VALUES" FLOAT) UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX("TimeStamp1");
.QUIT
.LOGOFF
.EXIT
```

And the insertion Statement looks like the following:

```
.logmech LDAP
.logon databae/user_id,pwd
.set width 256
.set retcancel on database libname;
DATABASE libname;
.IMPORT VARTEXT FILE =/path_to_file/data.csv, skip=1;
.REPEAT *
USING "SEPAL_LENGTH" (varchar(2000)),  "SEPAL_WIDTH" (varchar(2000)),  "PETAL_LENGTH" (varchar(2000)),  "PETAL_WIDTH" (varchar(2000)),  "TARGET" (varchar(2000)),  "TIMESTAMP1" (varchar(2000)),  "NULL_VALUES" (varchar(2000)) 
INSERT INTO IRIS_delete VALUES(cast( :"SEPAL_LENGTH"  as FLOAT), cast( :"SEPAL_WIDTH"  as FLOAT), cast( :"PETAL_LENGTH"  as FLOAT), cast( :"PETAL_WIDTH"  as FLOAT), cast( :"TARGET"  as FLOAT), cast( :"TIMESTAMP1"  as TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS.S(6)'), cast( :"NULL_VALUES"  as FLOAT));
.QUIT
.LOGOFF
.EXIT
```

By executing the insert statement I get the error:

> *** Failure 6760 Invalid timestamp.
>                   Statement# 1, Info =0

Here are some examples for the csv:

> |sepal_length|sepal_width|petal_length|petal_width|target|TimeStamp1|Null_values
>   0|5.1|3.5|1.4|0.2|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|
>
> 1|4.9|3.0|1.4|0.2|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|
>
> 2|4.7|3.2|1.3|0.2|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|
>
> 3|4.6|3.1|1.5|0.2|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|
>
> 4|5.0|3.6|1.4|0.2|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|
>
> 5|5.4|3.9|1.7|0.4|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|
>
> 6|4.6|3.4|1.4|0.3|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|
>
> 7|5.0|3.4|1.5|0.2|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|
>
> 8|4.4|2.9|1.4|0.2|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|
>
> 9|4.9|3.1|1.5|0.1|0.0|2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|

Do you know what is wrong with the timestamp?

Comment: `SKIP=1` is skipping the first row containing header information. Then your input data is beginning with an integer that is mapped to `sepal_legnth` in your USING statement. This means the `0.0` values in your input data are being CAST to a TIMESTAMP possibly that is what is generating the error.

Comment: @RobPaller  I dont understand it. I cast the first incoming value as a FLOAT and not as a Timestamp. The Timestamp is defined only later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mimi, the number and order of column in your bteq script and data file are not matching
Check below sample for columns specified in script and number of column in file

```
"SEPAL_LENGTH" (1),  "SEPAL_WIDTH"(2),  "PETAL_LENGTH"(3),  "PETAL_WIDTH"(4),  "TARGET"(5),  "TIMESTAMP1"(6),  "NULL_VALUES"(7)

col1->0|  col2->5.1|  col3->3.5|  col4->1.4|  col5->0.2|  col6->0.0|  col7->2018-09-18 13:26:30.583216|  col8->
```

You can resolve your issue by adding 1 more column before the timestamp column in your table and bteq script like below where I added "TARGET1" before timestamp column

```
USING "SEPAL_LENGTH" (varchar(2000)),  "SEPAL_WIDTH" (varchar(2000)),  "PETAL_LENGTH" (varchar(2000)),  "PETAL_WIDTH" (varchar(2000)),  "TARGET" (varchar(2000)),  "TARGET1" (varchar(2000)),  "TIMESTAMP1" (varchar(2000)),  "NULL_VALUES" (varchar(2000)) 
INSERT INTO IRIS_delete VALUES(cast( :"SEPAL_LENGTH"  as FLOAT), cast( :"SEPAL_WIDTH"  as FLOAT), cast( :"PETAL_LENGTH"  as FLOAT), cast( :"PETAL_WIDTH"  as FLOAT), cast( :"TARGET"  as FLOAT), cast( :"TARGET1"  as FLOAT), cast( :"TIMESTAMP1"  as TIMESTAMP(6) FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DDBHH:MI:SS.S(6)'), cast( :"NULL_VALUES"  as FLOAT));
```